# Eigenvector centrality as a limiting case of Katz centrality

Tags: linear-algebra, limits, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, network

In *Networks* by Newman (2nd ed.), eigenvector centrality (sometimes called Bonacich centrality) is defined as the vector $x$ that solves
$$
A x = \kappa x,
$$
where $\kappa$ is the principal (largest, most positive) eigenvalue of the adjacency matrix $A$. Katz centrality is defined as the vector $y$ that solves
$$
y = \alpha A y + \bf 1,
$$
where $0 \leq \alpha < \kappa^{-1}$ and $\bf 1$ is a conforming vector of ones. That is, $y = ({\bf I} - \alpha A)^{-1} {\bf 1}$.

**Question:** *In the book (p.164), it states that in the limit as $\alpha \nearrow \kappa^{-1}$, Katz centrality converges to eigenvector centrality. How can I prove this?*

Thoughts so far:

- I understand that, when it exists, $y = ({\bf I} - \alpha A)^{-1} {\bf 1} = {\bf 1} + \alpha A {\bf 1} + \alpha^2 A^2 {\bf 1} + ...$. This sum diverges when $\alpha = \kappa$. At that point, $\det({\bf I} - \alpha A) = 0$. This means that $\det(\alpha^{-1}{\bf I} - A) = 0$, which is the characteristic equation whose roots $\alpha^{-1}$ are the eigenvalues of $A$. This means that $({\bf I} - \alpha A)^{-1} {\bf 1}$ is well-defined for $\alpha \in [0, \kappa^{-1})$. I'm not sure how to incorporate this into the final proof.
- The book mentions that centrality of a node is only meaningful relative to the centrality of other nodes. So perhaps I should assume that eigenvector centrality, for example, should be defined as $\mathcal C^{e} = \frac{x}{\|x\|}$ and Katz centrality as $\mathcal C^{k} = \frac{y}{\|y\|}$.

**Edit:**

I have posted my attempt at a solution below. I would still like to verify some aspects of it.

Comment: Is the network directed or not?

Comment: @eranreches Both eigenvector and Katz centrality are defined for both directed and undirected networks. So, it'd be better to assume that the network is directed.

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume that the network is undirected, so symmetric, and further that the graph is irreducible (equivalent to connected) so the strict form of the Perron-Frobenius Theorem holds. Write out $A$ in the spectral decomposition so that
$$A=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i v_iv_i^T,$$where the $v_i$ are the eigenvectors (and form an orthonormal basis) and $\kappa_1=\lambda_1>\lambda_2\geq \ldots\geq \lambda_n>-\kappa$ are the eigenvalues. By the Perron-Frobenius Theorem, $v_1>0$ componentwise. This is $x$ in your notation. It follows from the von Neumann bound you used that for $\alpha<\kappa^{-1}$,
$$ (I-\alpha A)^{-1}=\frac{1}{1-\alpha\kappa}xx^T +\sum_{i=2}^n \frac{1}{1-\alpha \lambda_i}v_iv_i^{T}.
$$

We now compute
\begin{align}
(I-\alpha A)^{-1}\mathbf{1}=\frac{1}{1-\alpha\kappa}x(x^T\mathbf{1}) +\sum_{i=2}^n \frac{1}{1-\alpha \lambda_i}v_i(v_i^{T}\mathbf{1}).
\end{align}

The eigenvector centrality ranking cares only about the relative values of the components, so we may safely multiply by the scalar $1-\alpha \kappa$. This gives

$$(1-\alpha \kappa)(I-\alpha A)^{-1}\mathbf{1}=x(x^T\mathbf{1})+ \sum_{i=2}^n \frac{1-\alpha \kappa}{1-\alpha \lambda_i}v_i(v_i^{T}\mathbf{1}).$$ As $\alpha\to \kappa^{-1}$, the terms in the sum vanish as the denominators are bounded away from $0$ by the strict inequality in Perron-Frobenius, and this converges to $x(x^T\mathbf{1})$. $x^T\mathbf{1}$ is just some positive scalar from the Perron-Frobenius Theorem, so the limiting vector is $x$ up to a scalar factor.

Comment: +1: Although I mostly interested in the case of directed graphs, this is a really great proof for this case. Thanks!

Comment: @jmbejara Thanks! In the directed case, assuming strong connectivity so Perron-Frobenius still holds, I think one can still do this using the SVD. $x$ is an eigenvector corresponding to $\kappa$, so also of $I-\alpha A$, so $I-\alpha A=(1-\alpha \kappa) xx^T+\sum_{i=2}^n (1-\alpha \sigma_i)u_{i,\alpha}v_{i,\alpha}^T$, where $u_{i,\alpha}$ and $v_{i,\alpha}$ are the left/right singular vectors. Then $(I-\alpha A)^{-1}=(1-\alpha \kappa)^{-1} xx^T+\sum_{i=2}^n (1-\alpha \kappa)^{-1}v_{i,\alpha}u_{i,\alpha}^T$, and the same derivation should work I think. I might be missing something obvious.

Comment: Cool! Do we need some condition to say that $u_{1,\alpha} = v_{1,\alpha} = x$?  I'm not sure what conditions we might need to add (if any) to say that if $\kappa$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $\kappa$ is a singular value of $A$. We already have $\kappa > 0$.

Comment: Ah I see. Maybe the Jordan normal form is the right way to go? Intuitively, writing $A=P^{-1}\Lambda P$ where $\Lambda$ consists of Jordan blocks where the Jordan block for $\kappa$ is simple, then $I-\alpha A=P^{-1}(I-\alpha \Lambda)P$. $(I-\alpha \Lambda)^{-1}$ is in (a more complicated) Jordan form, but the diagonals get inverted and the off-diagonals for other Jordan blocks aren't too bad, so multiplying by $1-\alpha \kappa$ should kill every term in the limit of the Jordan blocks except leave a $1$ on the top diagonal. I think the resulting rank one matrix is $xx^T$, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the definition of Eigenvector centrality given above where $\mathcal C^e = \frac{x}{\|x\|}$ and the definition of Katz centrality, where 
$\mathcal C^k(\alpha) = \frac{({\bf I} - \alpha A)^{-1} {\bf 1}}{\|({\bf I} - \alpha A)^{-1} {\bf 1}\|}$.
When $\alpha < \kappa^{-1}$, recall that we can write
$y = ({\bf I} - \alpha A)^{-1} {\bf 1} = {\bf 1} + \alpha A {\bf 1} + \alpha^2 A^2 {\bf 1} + ...$.

Define $a_n(\alpha) = {\bf 1} + \alpha A {\bf 1} + \alpha^2 A {\bf 1}\, + ... + \, \alpha^n A^n {\bf 1}$, let $a_0 = {\bf 1}$. Define $b_n(\alpha) = \|a_n(\alpha)\|$.

Given these definitions, we would like to calculate the limit
$$
\lim_{\alpha \nearrow \kappa^{-1}} \mathcal C^k(\alpha)
 = \lim_{\alpha \nearrow \kappa^{-1}} \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{a_n(\alpha)}{b_n (\alpha)}, 
$$
where $\kappa$ is the principal eigenvalue of $A$.

Note that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n/b_n$ is defined for all values
$\alpha \in [0, \kappa^{-1})$. Also, $a_n$ and $b_n$ are finite for $n < \infty$. We can thus switch the order of the limits so that
$$
\lim_{\alpha \nearrow \kappa^{-1}} \mathcal C^k(\alpha)
 = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \lim_{\alpha \nearrow \kappa^{-1}} \frac{a_n(\alpha)}{b_n(\alpha)} 
= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{a_n(\kappa^{-1})}{b_n(\kappa^{-1})} 
$$

Define 
$$
x_{n+1} = \frac{A^{n+1} x_0}{\|A^{n+1} x_0\|},
$$
with $x_0 = {\bf 1}$. Assuming the needed conditions for the [power iteration algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration), $x_{n+1} \rightarrow x$, where $x$ is an eigenvector associated with principal eigenvalue of $A$.

Since $\det \left({\bf I} - \frac{1}{\kappa} A\right) = 0$, we know that $a_n$ and $b_n$ diverge when $\alpha = \kappa^{-1}$. Assume that $A$ is nonnegative (network edge weights are nonnegative). Then $b_n$ is also strictly monotonic. This allows us to use the [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem):
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n}.
$$
Calculating,
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n} =
\frac{\alpha^{n+1} A^{n+1} {\bf 1}}{\|a_{n+1}\| - \|a_n\|}
= \frac{\kappa^{-n-1} \|A^{n+1} {\bf 1}\| \, x_{n+1} }{\|a_{n+1}\| - \|a_n\|}
\geq
\frac{\kappa^{-n-1} \|A^{n+1} {\bf 1}\| \, x_{n+1} }{\|\kappa^{-n-1} A^{n+1} {\bf 1}\|}
= x_{n+1},
$$
where the inequality follows from the reverse triangle inequality.
Since $\|a_n(\kappa^{-1})\|$ diverges and is monotonically increasing, the inequality holds with equality in the limit. Thus, 
$$
\lim_{\alpha \nearrow \kappa^{-1}} \mathcal C^k(\alpha)
 = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{a_n(\kappa^{-1})}{b_n(\kappa^{-1})} = 
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x_n = x = \mathcal C^e.
$$

*Notes:*

- I should probably be a little more careful about switching the order of the limits.
- I should clarify the conditions needed for power iteration. (See Perron-Frobenius.)